# Mapbox osm buildings extrude heights

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

This example demonstrates extrusion of buildings polygons with constant height data: jsfiddle.net/yedg641a/

Another example, on mapbox tutorial site, demonstrated extrusion based on height data from vector tiles.
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/

Are there any possibilities to achieve this effect without using mapbox services, like example on js fiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `'fill-extrusion-height': 10` to `'fill-extrusion-height': ['get', 'render_height']` per https://openmaptiles.org/schema/#building

http://jsfiddle.net/1y8euv3d/